MFA Not Required on Chromebook for Microsoft 365, But Required on Windows OS
When logging into the Microsoft 365 website from a Chromebook, only the username and password are required, and MFA (Multi-Factor Authentication) is not prompted, even though MFA is mandatory. However, when using the same account on a Windows OS, MFA is required.
While enabling "Block Access for Unknown or Unsupported Device Platforms" is an option, it's not permitted in our environment.
How can I ensure that MFA is required for Microsoft 365 logins from Chromebooks without violating our policy on device platform restrictions?
I have created a new profile that blocks all devices except Windows, MacOS, Android, iOS, and Linux, and access is only allowed if the MFA is approved. But, no luck.

Found the Solution. Added target resources All Cloud Apps.
